# What is the difference between just declaring array of object and actually creating instance of it?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Why does first statement output "nothing1" and the second statement doesn't? If I am not wrong, then newly created array of object in statement second has default reference null.

```
class Solution
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Animal temp1[]=null;//statement first;
        if(temp1==null)
           System.out.println("nothing1");
        Animal temp2[]=new Animal[5];//statement second;
        if(temp2==null)
           System.out.println("nothing2");
    }
}
class Animal
{
    int name;
    int action;
    public Animal(int name, int action) {
        this.name = name;
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first statement

```
Animal temp1[]=null;
```

declares an array variable and initializes it to null. Therefore "nothing1" is printed.

The second statement

```
Animal temp2[]=new Animal[5];
```

declares an array variable and initializes it to an array of length 5. The elements of this array (such as `temp2[0]`) are initially all `null`, but the array reference itself (`temp2`) is not null. Therefore "nothing2" is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

In first case array has not been assigned any memory but in later case you have initialized your array,so it will take some memory block to get initialized and hence its reference will now point to a memory location and will not be null